# Remove hyphens from chapter, section titles

Tags: sectioning, chapters, hyphenation, parts

How do I remove hyphenating from all the `\part{}`, `\chapter{}`, `\section{}`, etc., titles of a document?

Comment: It will depend on the specifics of your document, a sample MWE for which you have not posted.  Going ragged right will prevent hyphenation and is often done with large point-size title lines.

Comment: For example, in `article` class, there is a definition `\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}`.  The term `\raggedright` can be added after `\bfseries` to remove full justification and thus hyphenation.  But don't go editing your class files directly.  Tell us more about your document class and preamble.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm using `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When disabling hyphenation, be sure to switch from full justification to `\raggedright`, or `\centering` in the case of part-level headers

Since you're using the `book` document class, I suggest you employ the facilities of the `sectsty` package:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\partfont{\centering}
\chapterfont{\raggedright}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hyphenation only occurs with full justification (unless the `ragged2e` package is employed, hat tip Mico).  For large point-size titles, it is frequently disabled by invoking `\raggedright`.  That can be made standard for your document by redefining that particular sectioning command.

For example, you can go to the `book` documentclass, copy the definitions of the sectioning that requires modification, and use `\makeatletter...\makeatother` redefinitions to add `\raggedright`.

I demonstrate it here, mid-document, but you should do it in the preamble.

These sort of changes can also be done with the `titlesec` package, but I will let someone else post that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a long title that requires extraordinary hyphenation}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}}
\makeatother
\section{This is a long title that requires extraordinary hyphenation}

\end{document}
```

[image]